# Join strings with XML node between in scala

Tags: xml, scala

I have a list of strings and I need to join them together with <br/> tags in between. So starting from:

```
val list = List("line1", "line2", "line3")
```

I need to end up with a NodeSeq of:

```
line1<br/>line2<br/>line3
```

It's possible the list contains only one element, in which case I should end up with a NodeSeq just of Text("line1").

Is there a one-liner to do this, using one of the higher order functions on list? I've tried to play around with foldLeft but can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list.map(scala.xml.Text(_):scala.xml.NodeSeq).reduce(_ ++ <br /> ++ _)
```

Note that we have to widen the type to `scala.xml.NodeSeq` manually as `Text` is too restrictive for the `reduce` method. The more concise

```
list.map(scala.xml.Text).reduce(_ ++ <br /> ++ _)
```

won’t compile.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I get a compile error on "reduce" saying the method wasn't found in list. I need to use reduceLeft or reduceRight, correct?

Comment: Ah that's why. I started up console in a random project on my machine, which turns out was 2.8.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), there's `intersperse`:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

list.map(xml.Text(_): xml.Node).intersperse(<br/>): xml.NodeSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what Debilski has answered. Just another way of achieving the same is,

`import scala.xml._`

`XML.loadString("<root>" + list.mkString("<br/>") + "</root>").child:NodeSeq`

But using map/reduce is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: That pretty much breaks on invalid input such as `List("<")`.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the problem, but this is unsanitized input. Your approach works, but if the list contains strings like "<b>asdf</b>", they get parsed rather than displayed, leaving a webapp open to attack.